# Remote Debugging with Microsoft Embedded Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, remote-debugging

I need to attach remote debugger to the process running on Telmet320 device. The executable for that device is build using Microsoft Embedded Visual C++ 4.0. I have a connected device, source of application and Embedded Visual Studio installed on my desktop. But I do not see a possiblity for the remote debuggin in Visual Studio itself. Also I did not find remote tool for Embeded Visual studio (Not sure if they are exist at all).

Any help will be very valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. In Embedded Visula C++ goto to Build -> Start Debug -> Attach to WCE Process ...